# Magento extension to allow a customer access until a certain date

Tags: magento

Does anyone know if there's already a magento extension that can restrict customer access on a given date. Example a user will only be able to login from dateA to dateB.

I've found Customer Activation extension, but it's only a flag that enable/disable customer login.

Thanks,
czetsuya

Comment: why don't you modify the extension that you found? It's just add a simple time range to check login!

Comment: Hi yes, that's actually what I did. I just thought that it was already done since it seems a common feature. To those interested in how I did it here's the link: http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2011/12/create-magento-extension-that-will-only.html

Answer (score 0):

AheadWorks SARP would be good for this - it's not free, but it should do what you are talking about

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments.html